# Orthogonality, closure and direct sum of subspaces in Hilbert Spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, hilbert-spaces, orthogonality

I'm struggling to get my head around Hilbert spaces and orthogonality. I've been using this example as a reference point to help deepen my understanding but I still have some questions.

We have the Hilbert space $H = L^2$, whose elements are real valued sequences
$x = (ξ_{j} ) = (ξ_{1}, ξ_{2}, . . .)$ such that

$\sum_{j=1}^∞ |ξ_{j}|^2 < ∞$,

with inner product

$\langle$ x, y $\rangle$ $= \sum_{j=1}^∞ ξ_jη_j$ 
, for every $x, y ∈ L^2$
where $x = (ξ_1, ξ_2, . . .)$ and $y = (η_1, η_2, . . .)$.

Consider now the set $Y ⊂ L^2$ defined in the following way:
$y ∈ Y ⇐⇒ y ∈ L^2$ and  $∃ N_y ∈ N$ :

$η_j = 0$ for every $j > 2N_y$,

$η_{2i} = 0$ for every $i = 1, 2, . . . , Ny$

(The last part should be a piecewise function but I'm unsure how to create one in MathJax).

The things that I am finding difficult to do of my own accord are: showing that $Y$ is a subspace of $L^2$, showing whether $Y$ is closed or not and proving it, finding $Y^⊥$ and showing that $L^2$ is not the direct sum of $Y$ and $Y^⊥$.

Answer (score 2):

A simpler description of $Y$ is: it consists of sequences $(a_n)$ whose only non -zero entries are the first few odd ones. (This means $a_n=0$ except when $n=2k-1$ with $ k \leq $ some integer).  From  this description you can see immediately that $Y$ is a subspace. $Y$ is not closed because the sequence $a_n=0$ for  all $n$ even and $a_n=\frac 1 n$ for $n$ odd is in the closure of $Y$ but not itself in $Y$. I will let you verify that $Y^{\perp}$ is nothing but sequences whose odd coordinates are all $0$. A sequence which is not in $Y+Y^{\perp}$ is given by $a_n=0$ for $n$ even and $a_n=\frac  1 n$ for  all odd $n$.

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful. Regarding $a_n = 0$ and $a_n = 1/n$ not being in the closure of Y, how would one go about finding the closure of Y?

Comment: @Kotomine The closure is all sequences $(a_n)$ with $a_{2n}=0$ for all $n$.

Comment: Thank you! What method did you use to find the closure?

Comment: @Kotomine for any sequence  in $Y$ we have $a_{2n}=0$ for all $n$ so the same must hold for any sequence in the closure. Conversely, if $a_{2n}=0$ for all $n$  the consider  sequences of the form $(a_1,a_2,..., a_N,0,0,...)$ (N=1,2,..). These are in $Y$ and they approach $(a_n)$ as $N \to \infty$.